# Как преобразовать SQL результат в массив python?

Tags: python, mysql

Как преобразовать SQL результат в массив python?

После выполнения SQL запроса я получаю ответ в виде

```
[{'token': '1234:ABC-HFJK8TYC67f'}, {'token' : '4321:HGF-HFJK8TYC67f'}, {'token' : '5648:LKB-HFJK8TYC67f'}]
```

Вопрос состоит в том, как преобразовать этот ответ в массив python в виде

```
tokens = [
    '1234:ABC-HFJKBLBJL6f',
    '4321:HGF-VZJ7JKBAA7f',
    '5648:LKB-DNJK8TYC67f',
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В python массивы называются списками (list).
У вас входящие данные и так являются списком, просто не строк, а список словарей (dictionary).

Словари состоят из ключа и значения, к которым можно обращаться. Вы бы могли в таком виде их и использовать.

В данном вопросе SQL не играет никакой роли, указывать это было не обязательно. Если бы Вы приложили сам запрос и таблицы, то другое дело.

Отвечая на Ваш вопрос:

```
d = [{'token': '1234:ABC-HFJK8TYC67f'}, {'token' : '4321:HGF-HFJK8TYC67f'}, {'token' : '5648:LKB-HFJK8TYC67f'}]

tokens = [] 
for i in d: 
    tokens += i.values()
print(tokens)
```

Создаём пустой список, добавляем в него значения из словарей, пройдя по входящему списку через цикл for.

Если мой ответ смог решить Вашу проблему, то буду рад, если выберете его, как решение (галочка). Удачных разработок!

Answer (score 1):

вынимаем из словарей значения ключа 'token':

```
lst = [{'token': '1234:ABC-HFJK8TYC67f'}, {'token' : '4321:HGF-HFJK8TYC67f'}, {'token' : '5648:LKB-HFJK8TYC67f'}]

tokens = [i['token'] for i in lst]  
# ['1234:ABC-HFJK8TYC67f', '4321:HGF-HFJK8TYC67f', '5648:LKB-HFJK8TYC67f']
```